# Set the maximum capacity of JList?

Tags: java, jlist, swingx

I am trying to set the maximum capacity of my `JList` to 5 elements. I can only seem to find a way of setting the minimum using .capacity(). Is there anyway of setting the maximum to 5 and for a dialogue box to be displayed when it exceeds this limit? So far I have this:

```
String getProcessName = "";
getProcessName = jTextField1.getText();
if (info.size() >= 5)
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"5 elements reached");
} 
else
{
  info.addElement(getProcessName);
}
```

This displays an error message but still adds the next value on to this list.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It should not add the element, are you sure you're not adding elements elsewhere?

Comment: A `JList` is populated programmatically, not by the user. So you have full control over how many items are in there. The code you have already looks vaguely like what you need to check you don't exceed your own maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

//Other frame "stuff"

JList list = new JList(new Object[]{"121", "131", "141", "151" , "111", "181"});
    list.setSelectionModel(new MySelectionModel(list, 5)); //<-- This is the magic line right here

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

> This accomplishes your task by setting the size of your custom selection model to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own ListSelectionModel that has the capacity to actively reject or adjust selection based on your requirements